# How to output as fast as possible a fixed buffer?

Tags: c, linux, macos, unix, fwrite

Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{

  unsigned char buffer[128];
  char buf[0x4000];
  setvbuf (stdout, buf, _IOFBF, 0x4000);
  fork ();
  fork ();

  pthread_t this_thread = pthread_self ();

  struct sched_param params;

  params.sched_priority = sched_get_priority_max (SCHED_RR);

  pthread_setschedparam (this_thread, SCHED_RR, &params);


  while (1)
    {
      fwrite (&buffer, 128, 1, stdout);
    }
}
```

This program opens 4 threads and outputs on stdout the contents of "buffer" which is 128 bytes or 16 long ints on a 64 bit cpu.

If I then run:

./writetest | pv -ptebaSs 800G >/dev/null

I get a speed of about 7.5 GB/s.

Incidentally, that is the same speed I get if I do:

```
$ mkfifo out
$ dd if=/dev/zero bs=16384 >out &
$ dd if=/dev/zero bs=16384 >out &
$ dd if=/dev/zero bs=16384 >out &
$ dd if=/dev/zero bs=16384 >out &
pv <out -ptebaSs 800G >/dev/null
```

Is there any way to make this faster?
Note.
the buffer in the real program is not filled with zeroes.

**my curiosity is to understand how much data can a single program (mutithreaaded or multiprocess) output**

It looks like 4 people didn't understand this simple question.
I even put in bold the reason of the question.

Comment: BTW `fork` doesn't create a thread. Not my DV/CV though.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I could use pthread.. but there is no speed improvement.. the bottleneck seems to be the pipe.

Comment: my curiosity is to understand how much data can a single program (mutithreaaded or multiprocess) output.

Comment: You should make that clear in the question.

Comment: Did you already tried "write(STDOUT_FILENO, ...)" ?
And are functions like sendfile() and vmsplice() suitable?

Comment: @SKi write is slower because with a so small buffer is better to use fwrite.. in all my tests any modification to the above code makes it slower... things get better when I raise the process priority and scheduler to Realtime and -20... but still is the pipe the bottleneck...sendfile afaik uses fwrite internally...about vmsplice I don't know,,, it expects an array of iovec structures...hmm

Comment: I updated the source raising the scheduling priority of the threads.
Also you must run it with sudo nice -n -20 to have full speed.

Comment: @Zibri sendfile() is a system call like write(), so it won't use 'high level' c-lib function like fwrite().

Comment: ok.. but did any of you compile my code and then his "version" and found that his version is faster on his machine?

Comment: Please,  @oguzismail remove the hold.. it is clear why I asked that.. infact people is trying to answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well it seems that linux scheduler and IO priorities played had a big role in the slowdown.

Also, spectre and other cpu vunerability mitigations came to play.

After further optimization, to achieve a faster speed I had to tune this things:

```
1) program nice level (nice -n -20)
2) program ionice level (ionice -c 1 -n 7)
3) pipe size increased 8 times.
4) disable cpu mitigations by adding "pti=off spectre_v2=off l1tf=off" in kernel command line
5) tuning the linux scheduler

echo -n -1 >/proc/sys/kernel/sched_rt_runtime_us
echo -n -1 >/proc/sys/kernel/sched_rt_period_us
echo -n -1 >/proc/sys/kernel/sched_rr_timeslice_ms
echo -n 0 >/proc/sys/kernel/sched_tunable_scaling
```

Now the program outputs (on the same pc) 8.00 GB/sec!

If you have other ideas you're welcome to contribute.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to determine your rate limiting factor.   It could be the cpu/memory speed, the cpu/system-call latency, the pipe implementation, the stdio implementation.   There are probably more, but that is a good start:

1. cpu/memory -- test how fast you can memcpy a bunch of zeroes.
2. cpu/syscall -- test, by writing 1byte to /dev/null, how long it takes to do a simple write on your system
3. pipe implementation -- you sort of have this, but you could try and vary the pipe capacity ( fcntl(2) F_GETPIPE_SZ. F_SETPIPE_SZ, if you are on linux).
4. stdio implementation -- replace fwite/setbuf with write.  I would suggest aligning your write size with the pipe capacity/num-processes might yield a good result, but you should probably investigate more broadly.

Try all of the above with multiple processes, although you might need to scaleup the memcpy ones to get meaningful results.

With these numbers, you should be able to calculate what your maximum throughput.  Please report back, I am sure more than a few people are interested.

Comment: hmm.. I tried all that... strangely write+buffer makes it slower than the code above. About the fnctl I didn't try it and I think that could improve things, but I have never used it... if you want to make some tests then you could post your code modification to mine if it's faster...

Comment: I just tried with F_SETPIPE_SZ after opening a fifo... the speed is slower by 30%... but you are free to try...maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: update: doubling the pipe size improves the speed.. but raising it further does not seem to improve the speed further.

Answer (score -1):

What you program does is:

1. Calls `fwrite`. That merely copies data from `buffer` to `buf`.
2. Once `buf` fills up it calls `write`.

To speed it up, avoid that copy in step 1 and `fwrite` and use `write` syscall directly. E.g.:

```
char buf[0x4000];
for(;;)
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, sizeof buf); // Implement error handling.
```

You may also like to make `buf` bigger to minimize the number of syscalls (Spectre mitigations made syscalls more expensive).

Comment: @Zibri It may be slow only if you write a small array. Write a bigger array, e.g. 4MB. You need to play with the array size to maximize your throughput.

Comment: I tried... and since I get the same speed as with the original program I'd rather keep it as it is... as I said the bottleneck is in the pipe 90%...

Comment: @Zibri You are right that it is I/O bound, but that unnecessary copying doesn't help.